# Python find partial matches of two data frame columns of different lengths

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frame columns of different lengths.
DF1:

| filename |
| --- |
| b~cute |
| b~cute2 |
| nan |
| b~cat |
| b~dog |
| nan |

DF2:

| filename |
| --- |
| sgjsg~12345~b~cute~v4.jpeg |
| jgsgj~1233~b~dog~v4.jpeg |
| jhdjd~1252~b~cat~v4.jpeg |
| sggsn~1252~b~cute2~v4.jpeg |

I am trying to do a partial match to create a separate column in DF1 with the filename as such

| filename | filepath |
| --- | --- |
| b~cute | sgjsg~12345~b~cute~v4.jpeg |
| b~cute2 | sggsn~1252~b~cute2~v4.jpeg |
| nan | nan |
| b~cat | jhdjd~1252~b~cat~v4.jpeg |
| b~dog | jgsgj~1233~b~dog~v4.jpeg |
| nan | nan |

Comment: My first two tables are not populating correctly

Comment: what if some `filename` from df1 occurs in multiple records of df2?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it doesn’t

Comment: What is `nan`, a string or `NaN`?

Comment: @Corralien Empty NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a helper function and use it to create the column on DF1.

```py
def match_fn(fn, filenames):
    if not isinstance(fn, str):
        return None
    for filename in filenames:
        if fn in filename:
            return filename
    return None

df1.loc[:, "filepath"] = df1.filename.apply(lambda fn: match_fn(fn, df2.filename.values))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `regex`:

```
import re

# Create pattern and escape regex
pat = (df1['filename'].dropna().sort_values(ascending=False)
                      .map(re.escape).str.cat(sep='|'))

match = df2['filename'].str.extract(f"({pat})", expand=False)
out = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'filename': 'filepath'})
                   .assign(filename=match), on='filename', how='left')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  filename                    filepath
0   b~cute  sgjsg~12345~b~cute~v4.jpeg
1  b~cute2  sggsn~1252~b~cute2~v4.jpeg
2      NaN                         NaN
3    b~cat    jhdjd~1252~b~cat~v4.jpeg
4    b~dog    jgsgj~1233~b~dog~v4.jpeg
5      NaN                         NaN
```

Details:

```
>>> pat
'b\\~dog|b\\~cute2|b\\~cute|b\\~cat'
```

Comment: I forgot to mention why I used `sort_values(ascending=False)`. As regex engine is greedy, you have to put b~cute2 before b~cute in the pattern string else sggsn~1252~b~cute2~v4.jpeg will match with b~cute and not b~cute2.

Comment: Thank you! it works amazing on my small data set but it does not work for a larger data set. I will keep testing it

Comment: You can slice your first dataframe to build small regex (sort first before slicing) then apply it on df2.